# Laravel's Database Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to write a MySQL select query using Laravel's Database Query Builder

I have this mysql query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `tweets` WHERE `user_id` = 1 OR `user_id` in (SELECT `follows_id` from `follows` where `user_id` = 1)
```

I am trying to write it for Laravel

```
$users = DB::table('tweets')
         ->where('user_id', '=', 1)
```

how can this be done?

Comment: Look into defining relationships. Define a `Tweet` model, a `User` model and associate them, then you should be able to do `$result = Tweet::whereHas("User", function($subQuery){ $subQuery->where("user_id", "=", 1); })->get();`

Comment: Before following @TimLewis 's suggestion, i would suggest rewritting this query into `SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE tweets.user_id = 1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tweets INNER JOIN follows ON tweets.user_id = follows.follow_id WHERE follows.user_id = 1`  as it is more optimal if performance matters `OR` and `IN(SELECT ..)` tends to optimize to bit badly in MySQL.

Comment: I agree with both comments, as for the @TimLewis one, it won't work, because as far as I understand from the query what he tries to get is a list of all tweets for the user AND tweets from users that the logged in user follows. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @nakov True, but that can be an additional `orWhereHas()` clause. It's a little hard to answer this in Laravel terms due to having to guess at the relationships/query logic. I try to avoid the usage of `DB::table()` in favour of Models, but your answer should work fine.

Comment: nakov yes you are write thats exactly what i am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a SQL rewrite as `OR` and `IN(SELECT ...)` tends to optimize badly. 
The SQL result might be wrong as you didn't provide example data and expected result see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing those.

```
SELECT
  tweets.*
FROM
  tweets
WHERE
 tweets.user_id = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  tweets.*
FROM
 tweets
INNER JOIN
 follows ON tweets.user_id = follows.follows_id
WHERE
 follows.user_id = 1
```

I believe the following Laraval code should do that. But not sure as i didn't program in Laravel for some time now.

```
<?php
 $first = DB::table('tweets')
            ->select('tweets.*')
            ->where('user_id', '=', 1); 

 $second = DB::table('tweets')
             ->select('tweets.*')

             ->join('follows', 'tweets.user_id', '=', 'follows.follows_id')
             ->where('follows.user_id ', '=', 1)

            ->union($first)
            ->get();
?>
```

Comment: Works like charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this even though it looks ugly.

```
$tweets = DB::table('tweets')
         ->where('user_id', 1)
         ->orWhereIn('user_id', DB::table('follows')->select('follows_id')->where('user_id', 1)->pluck('follows_id'))
         ->get();
```